# Как написать правильный MySQL-запрос с EXISTS?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL-запрос:

```
SELECT sessid FROM priem WHERE sessid EXISTS (SELECT sessid FROM tbl_uploads);
```

Пишет:

> 1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'EXISTS (SELECT
>   sessid FROM tbl_uploads) LIMIT 0, 25' на строке 1

Что не так ?

Comment: EXISTS возвращает логическое значение.

Comment: Перед словом exists не может идти названия колонки. либо надо применять IN и тогда будет имется ввиду , что указанная колонка содержит одно из значений, которые возвращает подзапрос. Либо, если используется exists эта колонка должна использоватся в предложении where подзапроса, таким образом, что бы подзапрос нашел (или не нашел) записи по заданному условию. И в зависимости от того нашел он их или нет, exists вернет 1 или 0 которые и будут играть роль для where основного запроса

Comment: JOIN сделать этой таблицы, а не сувать его в условия

Comment: Это `WHERE sessid EXISTS` заменить на это `WHERE EXISTS`. (убрать поле sessid).

Comment: Работает ! спасибо

Comment: @AlexStassov без `sessid` будет работать неправильно, хоть и без ошибки.

Comment: Да так и получилось (

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, при написании запросов можно смело обходиться без `exists`, `any`, `all`, `right join`.

Сделайте это с помощью соединения таблиц:

```
SELECT p.sessid 
FROM priem p join tbl_ubloads t on p.sessid = t.sessid
```

Либо с помощью подзапроса:

```
SELECT sessid 
FROM priem 
WHERE sessid IN (SELECT sessid FROM tbl_uploads)
```

Comment: Denis, спасибо Вам за ответ ! Но мне exists был нужен чтоб я мог проверить есть ли снимки рентгена в другой таблице и если есть вывести миниатюры. Попробую сделать это с помощью Вашего кода. Спасибо!